# Refreshing Access Token

Tags: token

My Access Token is expired after 1 hour and videos are not uploaded in to you-tube due to invalid access token and every time asking for authentication.
How to reactivate existing token or refresh access token.

Comment: how is this related to programming?

Answer (score 1):

You schould use long-lived token. There are several methods to get it, but everything is well described here:
[Facebooke developers extending tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending)
If you want more precisious answer please write in which language are you trying to do that.